# FastCGI, Apache, Django and 500 Error

Tags: python, django, apache, fastcgi

I am getting 500 Internal error with Apache and FastCGI. Spent the whole day to find the reason :-/

### /etc/apache2/vhost.d/mysite.conf

```
FastCGIExternalServer /home/me/web/mysite.fcgi -socket /home/me/web/mysite.sock
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName os.me #That's my localhost machine
        DocumentRoot /home/me/web
        Alias /media/ /home/me/develop/projects/media

        <Directory "/home/me/web">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from all
                Order allow,deny
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

### /home/me/web/.htaccess

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

### /home/me/web/mysite.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

os.chdir("/home/me/develop/projects/mysite")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "mysite.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded",daemonize="false")
```

### /var/log/apache2/error_log

```
...    
[Sat Aug 07 01:41:13 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/home/me/web/mysite.fcgi": connect() failed
[Sat Aug 07 01:41:13 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/home/me/web/mysite.fcgi"
```

Executing of .fcgi file (it works as html page got status "200 OK" and was rendered as it should be):

```
me@os ~/web $ python mysite.fcgi 
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to help from #django irc channel (specially to zk).

```
FastCGIExternalServer /home/me/web/mysite.fcgi -socket /home/me/web/mysite.sock
```

Must be changed to (as apache should spawn fcgi processes itself):

```
FastCGIServer /home/me/web/mysite.fcgi -socket /home/me/web/mysite.sock
```

Comment: where do u make these changed i have the same error

Answer (score 1):

See

- http://iamtgc.com/2007/07/04/django-on-lighttpd-with-fastcgi/
- [WSGIServer errors when trying to run Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800584/wsgiserver-errors-when-trying-to-run-django-app)

Comment: I saw this links before but they aren't helping me to solve my problem. 
./mysite.fcgi render full html page as it should be. (I gave above string Status: 200 OK). File is executable and itself it works. But apache don't want to work with it. :(